# Set script to be executed at/after boot, with only write permissions, but no shell access on the target

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, init-script

Suppose you have write access to a Linux system, with root rights, but no interactive shell.

You can only write new files or overwrite existing files. Creation of (sub)directories is possible. It's possible to define file permissions.

How would you create a ba(sh) script, to be run after or at system boot?

**edit:** I do not have read permissions on the system either - only write permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what init setup the Linux system in question uses. All the more commonplace ones use text files (and lots of symbolic links) to determine what needs to be run at boot and in what order, whether that's a bash script for `sysvinit` or a [`systemd`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd) unit file or something for [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/index.html) or whatnot.

Figure out which init system is being used, then write an init file of the appropriate type with the instructions you want, and drop it into the appropriate directory.

Without more information than you're providing in your hypothetical question it's hard to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I don't know what Linux the system is using, thus my vague question. Thank you for your input

Comment: Then I recommend you look around `/etc` and see if you recognize some of the subdirectories as patterns. Alternately, see if `/sbin/init` is a symlink, and if so, to what.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have no interactive shell on the system, only write access - so figuring out what Linux is running is kind of hard.

Comment: hence my comment about looking at `/sbin/init` -- presumably, you have read access as well, or at least directory read access, or you wouldn't be able to know what you're uploading.

Comment: unfortunately I really only have write access..